# Get text of select option's label and populate it in a hidden input field

Tags: jquery, select, label

I would like to Get text of select option's label and populate it in a hidden input field.

I can get the value but i would like to know how to populate the hidden field when option is selected or changed. I am actually a jquery newbie so i really have no idea of the event associated with select option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m5A9U/

Code

Assuming your HTML is

```
<select id="select">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>    
</select>

<input type='hidden' id='hidden' value=''/>
```

jquery code would be

```
$("#select").change(function () {
    $("#hidden").val($(this).val());
    //alert($(this).val()) 
})
```

**EDIT** To get the label of the selected option try
`$("#hidden").val($(this).find('option:selected').text());`

Updated example : http://jsfiddle.net/m5A9U/1/

Comment: how could i get the label of the option instead of value ??

Answer (score 1):

I've just created this simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2TtV/5/). Follow the comments for a better comprehension. There's a solution using pure JavaScript and another one using jQuery.

-- EDIT --

Even if it's not part of your original question, here [jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/W2TtV/6/) is the way you can get the "label" instead value.

Comment: @techish sorry, I'd forgot to add event handling. Please, check it again.

Comment: how can i get the label of the selected option instead of value ??

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see some HTML to know exactly how you have your label setup, but here is a basic example:

```
$("#sel1").change(function () {
    $("#myInput").val(($("label[for=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]").text()));
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/Lh8Eg/6/

Comment: i want the label of the option actually

Answer (score 0):

To get the option label of select element. We can try this:

```
<select id="id_select">
    <option value="myval_1">Text 1</option>    
    <option value="myval_2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="myval_3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Then write script:

`$('#id_select option[value="'+ $('#id_select').val() +'"]').text();`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of values that you want to convert into human readable text based on the text in a select input:

HTML

```
<div id="current_values"></div>

<select id="id_select">
<option value="1">First Option</option>
<option value="2">Second Option</option>
<option value="3">Third Option</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
var values = [1,3];

for(var i = values.length; i >=0; i--){
     $("#current_Values").append($('#id_select option[value="'+ values[i] +'"]').text()+"<br>");
}
```