# How to get both value and label of selected Item

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, label

> My code on jsp :

```
<form:select id="accountId" path="accountId" >  
<c:forEach items="${accountTypeList}" var="var">
<form:option value="${var.accountId}" label="${var.accountNo}"></form:option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

> I want both value and label of selected entry in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check [Get text of select option's label and populate it in a hidden input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940680/get-text-of-select-options-label-and-populate-it-in-a-hidden-input-field)

you can use a hidden field and fill that field with javascript/jquery so when you submit that form you can get that value.

--update

if you still use accountNo in next page, you can add some temporary variable in your form class like accountNo2.

Comment: thank u for solution.But I want to display label(accNo) on next page and there is risk of changing accNo for that particular accountId in between time.

Comment: So currently what I am doing is :get selected accountId and then iterat through accountTypeList. My code is:        if(accountTypeList != null && !accountTypeList.isEmpty())
{ 
for(AccountModel eachAccountModel:accountTypeList)
    {if(eachAccountModel.getAccountId().equals(itzMobileModel.getAccountId()))
       itzMobileModel.setAccountNo(eachAccountModel.getAccountNo());
      }   }                                                                    But I don't think it is right way to do it

Comment: or you can add your accountNo to your value in your select option like combine accountID|accountNo together in view and separate them in your controller based on delimiter ( pipe  | in my case).